# Is it possible to put borders around row groups in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

Has anyone put borders around there row groups to help make their grid easier to read? If so any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getRowStyle`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-styles/#row-style) to specify which rows you need to style. In your case, you can find if a row is a normal row or a row group by checking if [`RowNode.group`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-node/) is `true`.

AgGrid only use `border-top` to style row border. `border-bottom` of a row is actually the `border-top` of the row below it which means you can style the `border-bottom` of the row group visually by styling the `border-top` of the first child in the group (`RowNode.firstChild`).

Here is an example:

```js
const getRowStyle = (params) => {
  const { node } = params;
  if (
    (node.rowIndex !== 0 && node.group) ||
    (!node.group && node.firstChild)
  ) {
    return { borderTop: "pink solid 1px !important" };
  }
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 63922354/is-it-possible-to-put-borders-around-row-groups-in-ag-grid]

Comment: This was great! I was able to get the functionality I needed. Thank You!